# AVX instructions in GNU GMP (MPIR/MPFR)

Tags: visual-studio, gmp

I have built and installed GNU AMP (MPIR/MPFR) on Visual Studio 2015. After that using the multiplication function `mpz_mul()` I get the multiplied result. Also I have benchmarked the execution time of `mpz_mul` corresponding to different sizes of input fed to this `mpz_mul`.

Now using "Release mode" gives much faster result than "Debug mode". And a quick Google search showed that probably Release mode uses some vectorised instructions of MPIR, which makes faster computation possible? Is it truly the case that is vectorised instruction (AVX) gives faster results or there is some other reason?

Any help in understanding this concept would be appreciated. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Release mode does a lot more things than autovectorization. In debug mode the compilers do very stupid things which slows things down a lot. And AVX can only be used in CPUs that support AVX